# Getting Method Signature Name form a SOAPMessage on JAX-WS

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws

I'm using JAX-WS to consume SOAP web services and I'm looking for an easy way to find the method that's being called via SOAP which generated my current SOAPMessage

I believe one way would be to check the SOAP Body first node (that's the name of the method called) but I don't have a clue on how to parse the SOAP Body from this SOAPMessage

As of now I can output the message to my console

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand your question, however:

if you're processing the soap message as part of a handler, you can get the service and operation being invoked from the SOAPMessageContext:

```
    QName svcn = (QName) context.get(MessageContext.WSDL_SERVICE);
    svcn.getLocalPart();
    QName opn = (QName) context.get(MessageContext.WSDL_OPERATION);
    opn.getLocalPart();
```

if you just want to deal with SOAPMessage in your client code, and want to know what element is contained in the SOAP Body:

```
    msg.getSOAPBody().getFirstChild().getLocalName()
```

The SOAPMessage exposes each part of the envilope as a DOM object, so you can do normal "DOM"ish things with it.

Comment: Is there any other way to get the operation name besides `MessageContext.WSDL_OPERATION`? It appears to be NULL in my message handler.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe useful for someone, this is the answer to FrustratedWithFormsDesigner question: It appears to be NULL in my message handler.

Please see this. This is exactly the explanation why it is null:

http://blog.vinodsingh.com/2009/03/how-to-get-operation-name-in-jax-ws.html